# Spring-boot redirects differently when hitting localhost vs host ip

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have a Java 8 Spring Boot (1.5.13) web server, behind an AWS Application Load Balancer. The ALB performs TLS termination.

The web server redirects users for various reasons (for eg. to a login page). As described in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.13.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html), I've set `server.use-forward-headers` to `true` in `application.properties` so the redirection happens correctly to the external (https) url, using the `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `Host` headers.

This setup works on Host 1, but a (near) identical setup doesn't work on Host 2. On Host 2, I've narrowed it down to the below. Things work if I curl `localhost`, but not if I curl `172.32.1.1` (host 2's ip).

Both commands below were run on Host 2. Any ideas on what could be causing the difference in response? (http vs https)

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-32-1-1 ~]$ curl -v localhost:8080 -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" -H "X-Forwarded-Port: 443" -H "Host: example.com"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> X-Forwarded-Proto: https
> X-Forwarded-Port: 443
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 
< Set-Cookie: SESSION=6a9d14f0-07f6-4f73-ae31-8232f2d9de5d; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Location: https://example.com/login
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2022 21:43:28 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-32-1-1 ~]$ curl -v 172.32.1.1:8080 -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" -H "X-Forwarded-Port: 443" -H "Host: example.com"
*   Trying 172.32.1.1:8080...
* Connected to 172.32.1.1 (172.32.1.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> X-Forwarded-Proto: https
> X-Forwarded-Port: 443
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 
< Set-Cookie: SESSION=cbf4800a-15a8-460a-a3db-d6e3c21c046e; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Location: http://example.com/login
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2022 21:42:50 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host 172.32.1.1 left intact
```

Host 1 and Host 2 are using the same VM Image, and WAR file. On Host 1, the 2 commands above both respond with https as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the IP difference between Host1's VPC (172.31.x.x) and Host2's VPC (172.32.x.x)

The default for `server.tomcat.internal-proxies` matched 172.31.*, but not 172.32.* - causing `X-Forwarded` headers to be ignored in Host 2. Updating the property fixed it.

**Default**

> server.tomcat.internal-proxies=10\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|192\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|169\.254\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|127\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|172\.1[6-9]{1}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|172\.2[0-9]{1}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|172\.3[0-1]{1}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}

**Updated**

> server.tomcat.internal-proxies=(127\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(172.32.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})

A few things I came across which were helpful: there's a handy properties reference [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.RC2/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). Also, all properties actually in use (including defaults) can be checked via the actuator link in your app `/actuator/configprops.json`

Answer (score 0):

It could be so many different things.  Here is where I would look off the top of my head.

- Firewall
- /etc/hosts
- Certificates
- Look at the nics, are the apps bound the same (0.0.0.0)

Comment: I'm not the most experienced in this stuff, but my understanding is: the curl requests are entirely over http (so no certificates involved), from the same host (so no firewall involved). hosts file is identical. Can you expand the point on nics?

Comment: I use a program call `netstat` which is available with most flavors of Linux, to check which ports are open and see how they are bound to NICs.

`netstat -lnp` is my default here, and it shows me the `Local Address` which is listening and on which port.  So my list may include `127.0.0.1:443` or and external IP like `100.82.80.36:443` or both, or `0.0.0.0:443`, which represents all of the NICs available.